# Is this right to write document.write(x=4 + ++x);

Tags: javascript, unexpected-token

it shows error when i run it like this.
but if i first use `document.write(x=4,++x); //45`
and then write again `document.write(x=4 + ++x )` it surprisingly runs and shows me output //4510

can anyone tell me why

Answer (score 4):

After the first write, `x` is 5 and `45` is written, then you do `x=4 + ++x` which evaluates to `x=4 + 6` which is `10`, so it writes 10, leaving you with 4510.